# Drawing a dot with Windows GDI

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, gdi

I am very familiar with the Windows GDI graphics API and there is a function I have been missing for ages: how to draw a dot ?

By a dot, I mean a small pattern of pixels, say a 3x3 or 5x5 square (possibly with corners omitted), all the same color.

My constrains are that I want to do this efficiently and with as little resources as possible.

- I could use the `SetPixel` function as many times as required (25 calls for a 5x5 square).
- I could probably use the `MoveTo`/`LineTo` calls with a thick pen twice on the same coordinates. But I am unsure that this will generate a full dot, and I don't like the idea of creating a dedicated pen.
- I can also use the `Rectangle` or `Ellipse` function, but these ones draw the outline and fill the inside and must be an overkill for such a tiny shape. (Not counting the fact that they require a dedicated pen and a dedicated brush.)

Do you have any insight on what could be an efficient and handy approach ? How would you do that ?

Comment: A dot is just a special case of a 1x1 rectangle :)

Comment: You need a 1x1 rectangle in **device coordinates**

Comment: With rectangle we are in about the same situation as with an Ellipse. I am updating my question.

Comment: My dots are not 1x1.

Comment: Rectangles are often not 1x1.  You can make them anything you like.  Very odd mental block btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least as far as I know, none of the available options is really ideal. That given, it seems to me that `FillRect` is probably the least problematic.

This requires that you create a brush of the correct color, but at least that's all it requires.

Comment: Yep, that one seems to meet my requirements. And instead of a brush, you can pass a color ! :) Alas, it must be a system color, not a user-defined one :(

Comment: Would painting with a patterned [brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162462(v=vs.85).aspx) be of any use in this case?

Comment: @YvesDaoust This is the way because the GDI overhead is almost the same for all calls puts the SetPixel to the slowest solution and FillRect to the fastest. much faster would be direct access to bitmap ScanLine[] (it is 100-1000x faster) but that is valid only for rendering to bitmap and not directly to window Canvas ...

Comment: @Spektre: yep, thanks for the confirm. Direct bitmap access has another drawback: it can require LockBits/UnlockBits calls, that are quite costly (as they can imply a format conversion).

Comment: @YvesDaoust try to step/trace single GDI call and you will see that all of that costly sub calls are there also (that is at least mine experience) but I am using VCL api so there may be different behavior and also VCL bitmaps lock are required just at the last draw back back-buffer operation